# Sharepoint Search : Use OOTB IFilter in Custom BCS connector

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, sharepoint-2013, bcs, ifilter

Using SharePoint Search you can already indexed a lot of **OOTB supported document types** (pdf, docx, etc.), in what I understood, SharePoint Search is using some IFilter for that.
In my situation, I've got some **pdf files to index from a weird location**, so I need to use a **custom BCS connector** to index the content. For the BCS connector, I'm alright, I already did some with correct bdcm file, entity, and service that retrieve the data (it's working right now to index a sql db).

***What I'd like to do is use IFilter already existing to index my pdf files***.
I still have the possibility to get the data from the files with custom code in C# and return it in a crawled/managed property.

But, ***is it possible to use existing IFilter to get the content instead of reimplementing it?***

Thanks a lot for your help.

*[I'm using SharePoint Search 2013, and BCS connectors]*

Comment: Hm, i thought that when you create new data source using BCS you only create new source of data but search engine applies all standard filters to it. This is not the case?

Comment: Yes, but for pdf file content for example, I can parse in C# the document and return the content in a property. It could be nice if I can just return all the document to the search engine, and it can index the content and the metadata of the document.

Comment: Have you tried calling base implementation or something like that?